# aes-256-cbc encryption and decryption

Tags: android, node.js, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am **encrypting** an **audio** file using [crypto](http://lollyrock.com/articles/nodejs-encryption/) npm module in node.js and trying to **decrypt** it in the **android** side using  the same algorithm and the key.

The **encryption code**  is :

> encyption parameters

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
    algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc',
    password = 'somepassword';  //encyption parameters
```

> encryption function

```
function encrypt(buffer) {
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password);
    var crypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(buffer), cipher.final()]);
    return crypted;
}
```

Now,for **Decryption** , we need to use some IV(***Initialisation Vector***) and as research says [not to use same IV for any two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049789/aes-encryption-key-versus-iv).

So, I just want to know now ***how customized IV can be set and random or separate IVs can be generated for each file*** in node.js using crypto or any other module during encryption.

It will be great if someone can help me out in this.

Comment: If you're using real passwords (few characters, limited character set), then you shouldn't use this node.js code. This does invokes MD5 to generate the key from a password which is not secure enough. You should use PBKDF2 to derive a key from a password with a random salt and many iterations (over 9.000). Then you would also need to generate a random IV.

Comment: Thanks @ArtjomB.
It will be much more helpful if you can explain more for a better and much more  clear understanding of it.

Answer (score 0):

to create the IV, use the following command to get 16 random bytes:

```
var iv = crypto.randomBytes(16)
```

then, when creating the cipher, change

```
var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password);
```

to

```
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, password, iv);
```

The IV will not be attached to the resulting ciphertext, so you will need to send it separately to the android side (it can be sent in plaintext).