# Laravel cookie encryption

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, cookies

Is Laravel hashing differently request and response cookies?

I am using main domain and subdomains, and have set up CORS and CSRF and if I exclude cookies from `EncryptCookies` class I see the same cookies in the response headers and request headers.

If I leave them to encrypt however, I am getting different "encryption strings", and don't know if that is acceptable behaviour?

`EncryptCookies` class is only listed under `web` part in `Kernel.php`

Comment: it might be because encryption != hashing.

Comment: lets call it "encryption string" instead :)

Comment: What I meant is: encryption does not have to give the same "encrypted string" every time. E.g. http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/rsa2.html

Comment: Well that was in fact my question...is that what is supposed to happen or not

Comment: I have not read the code, but I **think** yes, this is not weird. Especially of the payload also might be changing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For [Laravel Encryption](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/encryption):

> Laravel's encrypter uses OpenSSL to provide AES-256 and AES-128
>   encryption. You are strongly encouraged to use Laravel's built-in
>   encryption facilities and not attempt to roll your own "home grown"
>   encryption algorithms. All of Laravel's encrypted values are signed
>   using a message authentication code (MAC) so that their underlying
>   value can not be modified once encrypted.

For each encryption, the value are encrypted with [AES-256 / AES-128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) with different [initialization vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) and signed with different MAC, even if you encrypt the same value, the payload, returned value of `encrypt` always different. For easier understanding, you can check this example:

```
$value = Crypt::encrypt('foo');
// eyJpdiI6ImVoNEVlVWpnYUdwZ1JHRlJWSGlTZEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVThpWjJNWVBqZnVsWjhLVWNDXC85VHc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjFjMDRhOTM5ZThhOWRmYjk3Mzk0OWFmNTM3YWE1NDAzNzMxNWY5YTJmODMwNmQxZDE4NDllZGJkMjc1Y2I3ZmYifQ==
base64_decode($value);
// {"iv":"eh4EeUjgaGpgRGFRVHiSdA==","value":"U8iZ2MYPjfulZ8KUcC\/9Tw==","mac":"1c04a939e8a9dfb973949af537aa54037315f9a2f8306d1d1849edbd275cb7ff"}
```

The second attempt:

```
$value = Crypt::encrypt('foo');
// eyJpdiI6Ill5MmZleG5ycTBaZmQ5NnRDT3N3dVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTmgrRnlqajJjUk9qTk1qeHJLU21LUT09IiwibWFjIjoiNWEzZDRjZWMwMjg0ZDhlMjhlZWRiODg3ZWQ5MTcxN2I5N2JjY2ZmMzc0NTYyOTI5MThmOTk4YjAyZjM1YTRjMyJ9
base64_decode($value);
// {"iv":"Yy2fexnrq0Zfd96tCOswuQ==","value":"Nh+Fyjj2cROjNMjxrKSmKQ==","mac":"5a3d4cec0284d8e28eedb887ed91717b97bccff37456292918f998b02f35a4c3"}
```

Comment: How does it know then if it is the same token if the encrypted values are different?

Comment: Crypt::decrypt() will decrypt it and the value returned to you will be the same. `Crypt::decrypt(Crypt::encrypt('foo')) == Crypt::decrypt(Crypt::encrypt('foo'))`

Comment: related link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049789/aes-encryption-key-versus-iv